# Create holes in spatial objects in R

Tags: r

I need to create a hole in a spatialPolygonsDataFrame based on a smaller polygon that it fully contains.

This illustrates the desired outcome using WKT-created polygons:

```
require(rgeos)
p = readWKT("POLYGON((1 1,5 1,5 5,1 5,1 1),(2 2,2 3,3 3,3 2,2 2))")
p = SpatialPolygonsDataFrame(p, data.frame(x=1))
plot(p, col='grey')
```

[image]

Now say we have the following polygon without any hole geometries, how can we insert the hole (i.e. without readWKT)?  I'm guessing an rgeos function but I can't identify the solution.

```
poly = readWKT("POLYGON((1 1,5 1,5 5,1 5,1 1))")
hole = readWKT("POLYGON((2 2,2 3,3 3,3 2,2 2))")
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
library(rgeos)
gDifference(poly, hole)
```

should do it.